# Query returning old results in ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

In my partial view I have a dialog box and a fancy tree is rendered. From the view on the list box change event I load the tree. When the tree is loaded I check to see if cache exists and if it does I pull from cache and if not then build and add the list into cache.

Cache itself is working correctly, but the method which pulls data to a list to be added to cache seems to pull older values. Since this method is trigged by ajax on this view, I suspect the issues lies within, I have tried to set no cache attribute in controller action method as well as sending a hard code cache bust paramater but to no avail.

**JS Listbox change event**

```
$('#SystemID').change(function () {
    var userroleid = $("#UserRoleID").val();
    //        if (userroleid != 1) {
    $("#treeview").remove();
    $("#partTreeView").remove();
    var overlay = $('<div></div>').prependTo('body').attr('id', 'overlay');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: serviceEntryURL,
        cache: false,
        datatype: "html",
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#main").html(result);

            overlay.remove();
        }
    });

});
```

**View Rendering the Tree**

```
 <div id="errorCodes">
        @Html.RenderTree(CacheHelper.ErrorCodes(@Model.ErrorCodeType), ec => ec.Name, ec => ec.Children.ToList(), ec => (ec.ID).ToString(), Model.ErrorCodes, "error")
    </div>
```

**Cache Helper**

```
  if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKeyRemove] != null)
                    {
                        ERRORCODES = (List<Domain.Lists.ErrorCode>)HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKeyRemove];
                    }
                    else
                    {
```

**//The following method GlobaList.ErrorCodes is not cached or anything but it still returns
older values. **

```
ERRORCODES = RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.ErrorCodes(instrumentTypeID);
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(cacheKeyRemove, ERRORCODES, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(10), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

                    }
```

**Error Code Edit Page**

If I go to this view and edit the error code and the cache key is removed successfully. When I go back to the view where i render tree, since this cache was removed, it queries the above method to build the error code list but the value I had just edited is not the correct and the old one. Whats even more weird is if I add a new record to my error code table and cache is reset, then the new record shows up correctly in the other view.

```
 while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (enumerator.Key.ToString() == cacheKeyRemove)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Cache.Remove(enumerator.Key.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced such error one time, It was a caching problem. In order to solve this problem, each time I send a new ajax request, I appended the url with a new random number.

Hope this helps you.

for example suppose the url is:

```
http://localhost/app1/getData?id=randomNb
```

Comment: I am passing data like this data: $("#form").serialize(),